# Selecting the rows that have observation for all of the years python

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset for students in a University, I wanna keep the observations for those students that did not drop out i.e. have observations for all for years
For instance:

```
Name        Year
Jacop       2010
Jacop       2011
Jacop       2012
Jacop       2013
Nina        2008
Nina        2009
Nina        2010
```

I need something like count the values by name, if it is smaller than 4, drop. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4)
print (df)
    Name  Year
0  Jacop  2010
1  Jacop  2011
2  Jacop  2012
3  Jacop  2013
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size') >= 4]
print (df)
    Name  Year
0  Jacop  2010
1  Jacop  2011
2  Jacop  2012
3  Jacop  2013
```

Comment: Can I ask you a question, if there are still 4 observations for Nina but actually one of them is NULL, still I am getting rid of the Nina ?

Comment: I think output is same. But if for name `Nina` is 4.th row with `Year=NaN` and need NOT count it use `df = df[df.groupby('Name')['Year'].transform('count') >= 4]` or `df = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: x['Year'].count() >= 4)`

Comment: You ca ntest it with `df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2010.0, 2011.0, 2012.0, 2013.0, np.nan, 2008.0, 2009.0, 2010.0], 
                   'Name': ['Jacop', 'Jacop', 'Jacop', 'Jacop', 'Nina', 'Nina', 'Nina', 'Nina']})
`